# Unable to install .NET Core 1.0 Visual Studio Tooling Preview 2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have a machine in our development network which doesn't have access to internet. I'm trying to install .NET Core 1.0 Visual Studio Tools Preview 2 from the executable available at Microsoft download store, however, it seems to be trying to download additional packages from the internet which of course fails. Microsoft doesn't seem to offer any offline installers and support team has closed one such issue without suggesting any resolution or workaround [Issue# 633](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/633). 

Any pointers to fix/work around this issue would be great.

Comment: Without access to internet you won't be able to use `dotnet restore` to retrieve dependency packages.

Comment: @Kalten yes, you're right, but towards that end I think I can create a local repository of nuget dependencies and choose to restore from there. However, here I don't have nuget dependencies. I'm referring to installation time dependencies which are other MSI packages required during installation not nuget packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install from command line using below command-

```
DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1
```

Refer this link where Microsoft has mentioned this workaround-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/windows-prerequisites#issues

---

**EDIT:**

If you are looking offline installers then refer these links-

Creating an Offline Installation of VS2015 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706497.aspx

advanced and specific downloads - https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#preview

Comment: This doesn't apply in the case mentioned above. The installer is not blocked. It's just that I don't have access to internet and hence not able to download installation dependencies.

Comment: Creating offline installation package is the actual solution to the issue as pointed out in this response. However, as mentioned by RaoulRubin, the offline installer package can be significantly larger than the standalone iso for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Asked the same question myself earlier.

I found this somewhat cryptic, but correct answer: [Dot net core 1 Tooling Preview offline installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316048/dot-net-core-1-tooling-preview-offline-installer)

You can create an offline installer by following the instructions here from MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706497.aspx

This uses the /layout option to force the download of all packages. (This can be very large!) These can be copied over as an offline installer.