# Dot net core 1 Tooling Preview offline installer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core

Is it possible to have an offline installer for [DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows) ?

Comment: Run with /layout command line switch please.

Comment: @LexLi Yeah, It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [@Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316048#comment67889154_40316048) for the answer.

Download the online installer from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows) then:

1. Creat a shortcut in the same folder.
2. Add the `/layout` switch (with a space)
3. Run the shortcut. It will download all dependencies in package folder.
4. After download completed, delete the shortcut and run the original installer.
   [image]

As I know the `/layout` switch works with most `Microsoft` online installers, but sometimes downloads lots of packages that may you don't need. So it is not recomended when you need only one time installation.

The **Visual Studio** installer downloaded about **25 GB** of files when I used this switch, but online installer only used about **4 GB** of data in my situation.

Comment: Here is the link to the full instructions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706497.aspx