# Visual Studio Tooling - Error Installing .NET Core 1.0.1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, windows-installer

I'm trying work with .NET core on a Virtual Machine that is blocked from downloading any content from the internet. It appears that the installer DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe requires an iis express package that it cannot download. The package is from:

https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/6/E/F6ECBBCC-B02F-424E-8E03-D47E9FA631B7/packages/ancm_iis_express_x64_en_69.msi

I can download this package manually and install it, but the VS2015 tooling installer still fails. I'm guessing that it uninstalls all ASP first, then re installs this package. (Previous step is "Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET")

Any ideas on how to work-around this problem?

Here is an abbreviated version of the installer log:

```
[1064:11B8][2016-12-06T14:59:24]i001: Burn v3.10.3.3007, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\3174400\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{C8F58DC9-B00E-4238-B5B3-613D0F1FD16E}\.cr\DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe

...many lines omitted...

[0B0C:0FC0][2016-12-06T15:04:23]i305: Verified acquired payload: Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\50e2672c-aefb-300c-8301-d8ebba628476\Preparation_69.exe.
[13C8:1134][2016-12-06T15:04:23]w343: Prompt for source of package: ANCM_IISExpress_x64, payload: ANCM_IISExpress_x64, path: D:\Installers\Core\packages\ancm_iis_express_x64_en_69.msi
[13C8:1134][2016-12-06T15:04:23]i338: Acquiring package: ANCM_IISExpress_x64, payload: ANCM_IISExpress_x64, download from: https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/6/E/F6ECBBCC-B02F-424E-8E03-D47E9FA631B7/packages/ancm_iis_express_x64_en_69.msi
[13C8:0B2C][2016-12-06T15:04:23]i319: Applied execute package: SetupBlocked_Install, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0B0C:13D0][2016-12-06T15:04:23]i301: Applying execute package: Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\50e2672c-aefb-300c-8301-d8ebba628476\Preparation_69.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\50e2672c-aefb-300c-8301-d8ebba628476\Preparation_69.exe" /d'
[13C8:0B2C][2016-12-06T15:04:23]i319: Applied execute package: Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET, result: 0x0, restart: None
[13C8:1134][2016-12-06T15:04:40]e000: Error 0x80072efd: Failed to send request to URL: https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/6/E/F6ECBBCC-B02F-424E-8E03-D47E9FA631B7/packages/ancm_iis_express_x64_en_69.msi, trying to process HTTP status code anyway.
[13C8:1134][2016-12-06T15:04:40]e000: Error 0x80072efd: Unknown HTTP status code 0, returned from URL: https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/6/E/F6ECBBCC-B02F-424E-8E03-D47E9FA631B7/packages/ancm_iis_express_x64_en_69.msi

...

working path: 'C:\Users\3174400\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{3817B9CE-FB46-471A-8ED3-9FA00C430E74}\ANCM_IISExpress_x64'
[13C8:1134][2016-12-06T15:05:52]e313: Failed to acquire payload: ANCM_IISExpress_x64 to working path: C:\Users\3174400\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{3817B9CE-FB46-471A-8ED3-9FA00C430E74}\ANCM_IISExpress_x64, error: 0x80072efd.
[0B0C:0FC0][2016-12-06T15:05:52]i351: Removing cached package: Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\50e2672c-aefb-300c-8301-d8ebba628476\
[0B0C:0FC0][2016-12-06T15:05:52]i351: Removing cached package: SetupBlocked_Install, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\f727b670-667c-3e6f-aafb-e48a72a2dea2\
[13C8:0B2C][2016-12-06T15:05:52]e000: Error 0x80072efd: Cache thread exited unexpectedly.
[0B0C:13D0][2016-12-06T15:05:52]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{da280276-4f5b-4918-8d40-20ca56dfa535}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0B0C:13D0][2016-12-06T15:05:52]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{da280276-4f5b-4918-8d40-20ca56dfa535}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[13C8:0B2C][2016-12-06T15:05:53]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80072efd, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

The interesting error is "[13C8:1134][2016-12-06T15:04:40]e000: Error 0x80072efd:... "

Please note that the VM has no internet access to make the download request.

Thanks, and sorry for the long error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this somewhat cryptic, but correct answer: [Dot net core 1 Tooling Preview offline installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316048/dot-net-core-1-tooling-preview-offline-installer)

You can create an offline installer by following the instructions here from MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706497.aspx

This uses the /layout option to force the download of all packages. (This can be very large!) These can be copied over as an offline installer.

Note that this technique should be good for other MS installers as well.